# shell script to skip line in while loop if output file with same date&time exists

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that creates images from files with certain date and time. This date and time is stored in `list.txt` file, few lines with same date and different time

```
2020 03 12 11 45
2020 03 12 10 23
2020 03 12 04 12
2020 03 12 00 23
```

I read this TXT file in a while loop:

```
while read line
do
    echo Line is... $line
    echo $line > $BIN/line.txt

    python3 $BIN/makeimage.py #creates image 
done < $BIN/list.txt
```

The filename of output images looks like: `filename_202003_1245.png`.

What's the easiest solution, to check if the file already exists and then skip to next line in `list.txt`? Now my script is just overwriting images again and again. Not sure if I have to delete line from `list.txt` as soon as image is created OR use `awk` - `grep` to extract hour and minute from `list.txt` and then from filename and compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `makeimage.py` script always names the files

```
filename_YYYYNN_HHMM.png
```

with a fixed string `filename`, you could perform the following modification to your script:

```bsh
while read year nr hr min sec
do
   echo "Line is >$year $nr $hr $min $sec<"
   fname="filename_${year}${nr}_${hr}${min}.png"

   if [[ -f "$fname" ]]
   then
      echo "File $fname already exists, skipping"
      continue
   fi

   echo "$year $day $hr $min $sec" > "$BIN/line.txt"

   python3 "$BIN"/makeimage.py #creates image 
done < $BIN/list.txt
```

This will assemble the prospective filename in the shell variable `$fname` and use the bash test operator `[[ ... ]]` to check if a file name `$fname` already exists in the current directory (if the files are in a different directory, prepend that in either the `$fname` variable or in the test construct). If so, it skips to the next loop iteration using the `continue` statement.

As side-note, you should always double-quote shell variables unless you explicitly want glob expansion and word-splitting to happen.